# Can a blend door be easily fixed/replaced in a Ford Escape Hybrid 2006? Also, passenger side airbag removal?

Tags: ford, ac, hvac, supplemental-restraint-system, escape

I recently got my AC compressor fixed, but after doing this it turns out my AC still isn't great because of a messed up blend door (according to my mechanic). Apparently this is a fairly common problem in Fords.  I did some searching around, and didn't find great instructions for my exact model, but it seems like the repair can be done through the passenger side airbag:

http://www.autozone.com/repairguides/Escape-Hybrid-2006-2008-Mariner-Hybrid-2006-2008/Blend-Door-Actuator/Removal-Installation/_/P-0996b43f8075c084

I was wondering 1) how to actually remove the passenger side airbag, and 2) if this repair is possible to do myself. I guess that a lot of people do perform this themselves on Fords and others using these kits from heatertreater.com, but again I couldn't find anything for my model. The heatertreater requires cutting into the plenum, which I'm hoping I won't have to do if the blend door is accessible through the passenger air bag opening.

Thanks anyone for the advice.

Comment: There are two blend doors. Do both sides of the A/C output exhibit the same temperature at the same time? If they do, I doubt it's the blend doors.

Comment: They do have the same temperature, but I think my car is EMTC (Electronic  Manual Temperature Control) rather than EATC (Electronic Automatic Temperature Control) since I just have a dial that moves from cold to hot.  According to the autozone guide, this would mean I have only the RH temperature blend door?

Comment: Another update is I ran a self-diagnostic and came up with no DTC error codes (would have been "B1239 Air Flow Blend Door Driver Circuit Failure" or "B1249 Blend Door Failure").

Comment: Correct on both counts.

Comment: Regarding the EMTC and door or the DTC codes?

Comment: Both. If EMTC, only right hand door. I was wrong on the two blend door count for your specific vehicle. DTC code(s) would show if there was a motor failure for the blend door. You are right on both assertions.

Comment: Thanks. I guess that leaves it as either a blend door or blend door actuator issue?